# A more efficient way of finding English words that are one letter off from eachother

Tags: java, algorithm

I wrote a little program that tries to find a connection between two equal length English words. Word A will transform into Word B by changing one letter at a time, each newly created word has to be an English word.

For example:

```
Word A = BANG
Word B = DUST
```

Result:

```
BANG -> BUNG ->BUNT -> DUNT -> DUST
```

My process:

1. Load an English wordlist(consist of 109582 words) into a `Map<Integer, List<String>> _wordMap = new HashMap();`, key will be the word length.
2. User put in 2 words.
3. createGraph creates a graph.
4. calculate the shortest path between those 2 nodes
5. prints out the result.

Everything works perfectly fine, but I am not satisfied with the time it took in step 3.

See:

```
Completely loaded 109582 words!
CreateMap took: 30 milsecs
CreateGraph took: 17417 milsecs
(HOISE : HORSE)
(HOISE : POISE)
(POISE : PRISE)
(ARISE : PRISE)
(ANISE : ARISE)
(ANILE : ANISE)
(ANILE : ANKLE)
The wholething took: 17866 milsecs
```

I am not satisfied with the time it takes create the graph in **step 3**, here's my code for it(I am using JgraphT for the graph):

```
private List<String> _wordList = new ArrayList();  // list of all 109582 English words
private Map<Integer, List<String>> _wordMap = new HashMap();  // Map grouping all the words by their length()
private UndirectedGraph<String, DefaultEdge> _wordGraph =
        new SimpleGraph<String, DefaultEdge>(DefaultEdge.class);  // Graph used to calculate the shortest path from one node to the other.


private void createGraph(int wordLength){

    long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
    List<String> words = _wordMap.get(wordLength);
    for(String word:words){
        _wordGraph.addVertex(word);  // adds a node
        for(String wordToTest : _wordList){
            if (isSimilar(word, wordToTest)) {        
                _wordGraph.addVertex(wordToTest);  // adds another node
                _wordGraph.addEdge(word, wordToTest);  // connecting 2 nodes if they are one letter off from eachother
            }
        }            
    }        

    System.out.println("CreateGraph took: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - before)+ " milsecs");
}


private boolean isSimilar(String wordA, String wordB) {
    if(wordA.length() != wordB.length()){
        return false;
    }        

    int matchingLetters = 0;
    if (wordA.equalsIgnoreCase(wordB)) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < wordA.length(); i++) {

        if (wordA.charAt(i) == wordB.charAt(i)) {
            matchingLetters++;
        }
    }
    if (matchingLetters == wordA.length() - 1) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**My question:**

**How can I improve my algorithm inorder to speed up the process?**

For any redditors that are reading this, yes I created this after seeing the thread from /r/askreddit yesterday.

Comment: Any reason to not use Levenshtein distance? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: Are you just trying to find the minimum number of transformations to create Word B from Word A? Are Word A and Word B the input parameters (ie KNOWN ahead of time)? In that case, you should use the Levenshtein distance as mentioned above. However, it sounds like you want to translate one letter at a time and that each intermediate word has to also be an English word? Yet if that is true and considering your example of "BANG -> BUNG ->BUNT -> DUNT -> DUST"...are BUNG and BUNT really English words? Or.. is only Word A the input parameter and Word B is the result of the transform? So confused...

Comment: @GreenieMeanie You can look up those 2 words on a dictionary if you are not familiar with them, those 2 are actual English words. And using Levenshtein distance has nothing to do with my question, the bottle neck with my program is pulling all the data from a text file and then connect all of them into a graph, which Jon already helped me solve, how to calculate the shortest path isn't part of my question(and i have no problem solving that part my self). I only asked how to break the bottle neck, if that wasn't clear to you in my original question, that's what I actually meant.

Comment: The original question is not clear at all, which is why the very first comment by a different person was asking why you weren't using Levenshtein distance.  Also, I don't think most people know or would even begin to assume that BUNG, BUNT, or DUNT are actual words, so that leads to another point of confusion.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a starting thought:

Create a `Map<String, List<String>>` (or a `Multimap<String, String>` if you've using Guava), and for each word, "blank out" one letter at a time, and add the original word to the list for that blanked out word. So you'd end up with:

```
.ORSE => NORSE, HORSE, GORSE (etc)
H.RSE => HORSE
HO.SE => HORSE, HOUSE (etc)
```

At that point, given a word, you can very easily find all the words it's similar to - just go through the same process again, but instead of adding to the map, just fetch all the values for each "blanked out" version.

Comment: Oh this is very interesting, I never thought of that, let me give it a try, thank you.

Comment: This is incredible! 17866 ms before,  2381 ms after, you are a god.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to run it through a profiler to see where most of the time is taken, especially since you are using library classes - otherwise you might put in a lot of effort but see no significant improvement.

You could lowercase all the words before you start, to avoid the `equalsIgnoreCase()` on every comparison. In fact, this is an inconsistency in your code - you use `equalsIgnoreCase()` initially, but then compare chars in a case-sensitive way: `if (wordA.charAt(i) == wordB.charAt(i))`. It might be worth eliminating the `equalsIgnoreCase()` check entirely, since this is doing essentially the same thing as the following `charAt` loop.

You could change the comparison loop so it finishes early when it finds more than one different letter, rather than comparing all the letters and only then checking how many are matching or different.

(**Update**: this answer is about optimizing your current code. I realize, reading your question again, that you may be asking about alternative algorithms!)

Answer (score 0):

You can have the list of words of same length sorted, and then have a loop nesting of the kind `for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) for (int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) { }`.

And in isSimilar count the differences and on 2 return false.